# Dotnet Maui AuthenticateAsync does not return any result

Tags: .net, maui

I expect to receive a WebAuthenticatorResult from the AuthenticateAsync() method.  Instead, the app will navigate to wherever the callbackURI points to.  I need to actually read the result to parse cookies received from the backend.

```
var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync(
                new Uri("https://example.com/signin-microsoft"),
                new Uri("myapp://")
            );
```

Please note, I do not receive a null response, it's as if the thread is stuck "await"ing the return from AuthenticateAsync() meanwhile the app has already navigated to the callbackURI.

Any help or thoughts would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: did you follow all of the instructions in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=windows#platform-differences)?

Comment: On which platform do you want to use this method?

Comment: Hi all, it turns out I was inheriting from the Activity Class instead of the WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity class.  It seems that said class can only be imported from within the Platform/Android/Resources directory.  Thanks

Comment: Android requires an Intent Filter setup to handle your callback URI. This is accomplished by inheriting from the WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity class.